# Can I use glMap1() to plot polynomials?

Tags: c, opengl

Can we use `glMap1f`/`glMap1d` to plot arbitrary polynomials?

For example, can I use them to plot p(x) = ax<sup>4</sup> + bx<sup>3</sup> + cx<sup>2</sup> + dx + e for arbitrary coefficients?

An example I currently have is below, which draws a parabola, but I can't figure out how to make it draw a polynomial with the parameters I want:

```
float const u = 0.25F;
GLfloat points [][3] =
{
    { 0, 0, 0 },
    { u, 2 * u, 0 },
    { 2 * u, u, 0 },
};
glMap1f(GL_MAP1_VERTEX_3, 0, 1,
    sizeof(*points) / sizeof(**points), sizeof(points) / sizeof(*points), &points[0][0]);
glEnable(GL_MAP1_VERTEX_3);
int const n = 1000 * sizeof(points) / sizeof(*points);
glMapGrid1f(n, 0, 1);
glEvalMesh1(GL_LINE, 0, n);
```

Comment: Why are you bothering with old and busted OpenGL-1.1 evaluators? No modern OpenGL implementation covers them, so you'll inevitably get the software fallback which is no more efficient than evaluating the equations in your own code. People, please let OpenGL-1.x die already and use shaders.

Comment: @datenwolf: well I'm using OpenGL 1.1 because (1) I know its basics, (2) it's easy to understand, and (3) it's highly portable/cross-platform, and (4) it's still faster and requires *much* less code for 2D in my experience than all the alternatives I know how to use (GDI, GDI+, DirectDraw, Direct2D, etc.). But hey, if you'd like to post a self-contained OpenGL 2.0 example that does what I'm asking for without a lot of fuss (i.e. don't make me download an extra 1GB SDK just for this) then I'm happy to move to version 2. I just don't have enough time to teach myself GLSL, how shaders work, etc.